# Assign text from select list to a Hiddenfor field using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to assign the text (not the value) from a MVC Html.DropDownListFor field to a HiddenFor field.

Right now I have the following code:

```
 @Html.Label("Departure Route:", new { @class = "label-travel" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DepartureRoute, routesSelectList, new { @class = "dropdown", @id = "Outbound-route" })
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DepartureRouteName, new {@id = "Outbound-route-name"})
```

I have tried to use Javascript / Jquery to take the selected field text in the dropdownlist and assign the text value to the model field (Hiddenfor)

What I have tried so far:

```
 var InitializeRouteNames = function () {
    $("DepartureRouteName").html = $("#Outbound-route option:selected").
};
```

Hope someone can see what I have done wrong.

Comment: Your hidden input has `id="Outbound-route-name"` so its `$(`#Outbound-route-name`).val($("#Outbound-route option:selected").text());`

Comment: Also, if you want to select by id, you need to prefix it with `#` or if you're trying to select by name, then you need the attribute selector syntax: `[name=...]`. When you just select a name without any additional syntax, it's an *element* selector, and there's obviously no `DepartureRouteName` element in HTML.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Stephan showed me how to do this in the right way. I forgot to use the val() method in order to assign the HiddenFor value.

```
var InitializeRouteNames = function () {
    $("#Outbound-route-name").val($("#Outbound-route option:selected").text());
    $("#Return-route-name").val($("#Return-route option:selected").text());
};
```